# Multiple value from one input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one input for address in this input people should type there address (street, number, entrance, floor, apartment - they must static in input) how can I make them bring them into this kind and not miss any of them. And then after that to take each value(street, number, entrance, floor, apartment) seperetly with PHP or Javascirpt?

[image: Example]

I want to get seperetly - Street name, 414, A, 3, 48 and the users cannot miss parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok but why don't you use more than just **one** input??? And do you really think everybody has a floor or ap to fill??? And if i'm correct, even some japanese has no street name...

Comment: @A.Wolff I want, but this is required ...

Comment: you can use `.split(",")` to split them into respective values. I think address is separated by comma. you can put that fact into use by splitting the value using comma

Comment: Why would you do this? This brings many validations that need to be performed. Multiple inputs would be better.

Comment: @SubliemeSiem I know, but this is not my wish.

Comment: @diank You mean you **don't** want but it is required? Who could required such unlogic behaviour? I've never seen any form in the web like that, it doesn't make any sense

Comment: @guradio Okay, but how to set str: , num: .... to be static?

Comment: So the user will have to know the he has to write `str:` then the street name and so on?

Comment: @diank check this simple demo https://jsfiddle.net/ycw20vg3/

Comment: @guradio I know how to get variable, the problem is how to show to users "str:", "num:" etc. in input and user write after that.

Comment: use `.val()` like https://jsfiddle.net/ycw20vg3/1/

Comment: @diank i think you are needing a `placeholder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer I can think of.

Make multiple inputs.

Otherwise, provide a clear syntax on the page of how you expect the user to provide the input.

You will also need a unique delimiter.

Then on form submit, in php

```
explode($delimiter, $string);
```

Or with JavaScript

```
.split("delimiter");
```

Consider using JavaScript to validate the form before the user can submit it.

Comment: This is hardly worth submitting as a answer/solution. Suggesting the use of `explode()` could be done in the comments section since this post doesn't offer any detail or example.

Comment: @NewToJS I provided multiple solutions based on the information I had. All are relevant. Sorry your don't agree.

Comment: @jjonesdesign this is not my wish, I want too multiple inputs, but my boss is sh*t(it's not developer).

Comment: @diank read my answer again, If you don't want to use multiple, I listed other options.

Comment: @jjonesdesign okay, but how to set static this text in input "str:" and etc, so user to know where and what to write?

Comment: @diank You could eventually set your own custom input mask **but** you really cannot hanlde all possibilities. For example someone living in a house has no floor and ap to fill. A street name can be really different regarding country, think about Tokyo. Tell this to your boss

Comment: @diank provide plain text before the input displaying the properly formatted input. Give the user an example of what you expect. PS. Tell your bosses boss you need a new boss.

Comment: @A.Wolff if living in the house they know to se "0" for the "entry" or "ap"

Comment: @diank And if they live in an house in Tokyo? Seriously, you (your boss) are just overcomplicating it for no reason...

Comment: `so user to know where and what to write?` a **placeholder** can do this job

Comment: @A.Wolff As i said my boss is just f*cking sh*t. I think something like this http://jsfiddle.net/pemep/

Comment: @guradio placeholder didn't do the job.

Comment: @diank I'd use some kind of elment to display user how to fill data and a textarea with for each line the relevant data to fill. But again, this is for sure a no go

Comment: @diank <input type="text" placeholder="some text"/>..... But this will disappear. I still recommend multiple forms.

Comment: @diank or use a single form, with hidden inputs behind it, using JS and a next button? lol.

Comment: @jjonesdesign the input must be like a blank(form or model)